# Websocket not working on server

Tags: php, node.js, websocket, ratchet, faye

I'm facing for the first time with WebSocket.
I used the example from here to create WebSocket https://github.com/leggetter/realtime-symfony-examples. I tried Faye and Ratcher method, and both work same.

My problem:
On local machine everything is ok, but on the server, it's not. First, should I set localhost or domain URL? 
I tried with domain URL, and because it's https, I use wss to connect on WebSocket and getting a connection timeout.
Then I tried with localhost, and it has been connected, but the client didn't receive any message.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Do you see any error in console at client side?

Comment: Yes. But when try with domain URL, i'm getting connection timeout.
With ws://localhost:8000, I see it's connected, but not receiving messages

Comment: Ok. I can confirm if use localhost, WebSocket is established.
But still, there is the problem why I don't get any message.
If someone has something in mind, just tell me to try